# Composer PHP version issue

Tags: php, shell, ssh, composer-php, putty

I'm trying to integrate Flagship API into a website. It uses composer for this, and I've never used it before. I figured out how to install it using Putty, and I tried running the command to install the API

```
composer require flagshipcompany/flagship-rest-client
```

This is the error I receive:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Package flagshipcompany/flagship-rest-client at version  has a PHP requirem
>     ent incompatible with your PHP version (5.6.30)

I've tried several things to change the PHP version the shell is using, including finding the files with the php version 7.1.14 and changing the paths in bash files. When I run

```
php -v
```

It returns

> PHP 7.1.14 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2018 18:28:03) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.2.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by ionCube Ltd.

Not really sure what the issue here is. I've tried changing the php version in CPanel as well, and no luck.

Comment: Btw. [php 5.6 hits EOL today](http://php.net/eol.php)

Comment: `php -v` shows the version of php-cli. What does `phpinfo()` return?

Comment: @AD7six looks like it worked, thanks!